# AUTOMATOR - Trying to issue a command inside a shell script with parameters received from AppleScript

Tags: bash, applescript, automator

I am creating this automator script for macOS that receives videos and extract a frame at a given time in seconds.

After receiving the videos from finder, it runs this applescript asking for the time in seconds, to extract the frame.

The time is stored into the Applescript variable "seconds".

When the applescript ends, I have 3 variables:

1. inputVideo, containing the POSIX input video path
2. outputVideo, containing the POSIX output video path
3. seconds, containing the time in seconds.

The applescript ends with these lines

```
    return fileInputPosix & fileOutputPosix & seconds
end run
```

and passes the variables to a shell script that starts with these lines:

```
fileInput=${@[0]}
fileOutput=${@[1]}
seconds=${@[2]}

/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i $fileInput -vf "select=eq(n\,$seconds)" -vframes 1 $fileOutput
```

The last line extracts a frame using `FFMPEG`.

I am having this error

> The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “ffmpeg version
>   4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers   built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)   configuration:
>   --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox   libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100   libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100   libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100   libavdevice    58.  5.100 /
>   58.  5.100   libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0   libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100   libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100   libpostproc    55.  3.100 /
>   55.  3.100 /Users/fireball/Desktop/HD/aaa.mp4/Users/fireball/Desktop/HD/aaa.png1000[0]:
>   Not a directory”

I think I am having some concatenation error on the command line string

If I would type this last line on terminal I would type like this:

```
ffmpeg -i aaa.mp4 -vf "select=eq(n\,1000)" -vframes 1 aaa.png
```

where `aaa.mp4` is the input video and `aaa.png` is the frame at t=1000s.

any ideas?

Comment: In addition to vadian's answer, also make sure the **Run Shell Script** _action_  is set to: **Pass input: as arguments**

Comment: ok, it is already adjusted like that. Thanks.

Comment: What was the purpose of involving AppleScript at all in the workflow.  It seems like a masochistic way to add a layer of complication to something just for the challenge.  I would recommend getting the required user input from the  **Ask For Text** Automator action, then passing that and the two Finder files directly to the shell script action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message the line `fileInputPosix & fileOutputPosix & seconds` returns one single string.

Maybe you want to return a list then you have to add braces and to replace the ampersand characters with commas and you have to convert the numeric value to text

```
return {fileInputPosix, fileOutputPosix, (seconds as text)}
```

To pass the variables to the shell script just write

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -I $1 -vf "select=eq(n\,$3)" -vframes 1 $2
```

or if you need the variables

```
fileInput=$1
fileOutput=$2
seconds=$3

/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i $fileInput -vf "select=eq(n\,$seconds)" -vframes 1 $fileOutput
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return {fileInputPosix, fileOutputPosix, seconds}`?

Comment: Duuuuhhhh! Obviously. Thanks. But now I am getting a different error when the shell script runs. `[NULL @ 0x7ff6f1005000] Unable to find a suitable output format for '1000[0]' 1000[0]: Invalid argument”`. How do I get the array elements on bash now?

Comment: thanks. I think we are almost there. Now I have a gigantic error message that is probably ffmpeg trying to run with the parameters provides. At the end, FFMPEG fails with the message `At least one output file must be specified”...

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ffmpeg`. And it's another question.

Comment: My whole question is about running a FFMPEG using automator + applescript + shell script...